# Why do I get a failed to read session_start()

Tags: php

I have just moved to a new webhost called Eurobia and just noticed that at times, I have been getting the following errors. Is this error due to the webhost?

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73/sess_45073c3b96060f25f10e5a1bd15e842b,
>   O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in
>   /home/pianocou/domains/pianocourse101.com/public_html/header2.php on
>   line 2
>
> Warning: session_start(): Failed to read session data: files (path:
>   /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php73) in
>   /home/pianocou/domains/pianocourse101.com/public_html/header2.php on
>   line 2

Comment: Looks like PHP is unable to read the session file. Either it's not there or it's a rights issue.

Comment: Is this a host issue because I have contacted the host but haven't received a reply yet